# gson.toJson(obj) local class

Tags: java

Why does `gson.toJson(obj)` return `null` when I do this?

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        if (user != null) {
            resp.setContentType("application/json");
            resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(user));
        } else {
            class Url {
                private String url;
                Url(String url) {
                    this.url=url;
                }
            }
            Url obj = new Url(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
            resp.setContentType("application/json");
            resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

When I define the `Url` class outside the `LoginServlet` class it works and returns a json string of the url object?

```
class Url {
    private String url;
    Url(String url) {
        this.url=url;
    }
}

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        if (user != null) {
            resp.setContentType("application/json");
            resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(user));
        } else {
            Url obj = new Url(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
            resp.setContentType("application/json");
            resp.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `Url obj = ...` results in something for gson to parse?

Comment: Yes, it does contain a url object?

Comment: According to [Gson.toJson( Object )](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object%29) it seems that you should be using [Gson.toJson( Object, Appendable )](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Appendable%29), which would look like `gson.toJson( obj, resp.getWriter() );`

Comment: Wait, so where is the Url definition when it's not external to the LoginServlet definition?

Comment: see new edit, I compile it like that.

Comment: `gson.toJson( obj, resp.getWriter() );` has the same result and only returns a string when `Url` class is outside the `LoginServlet` class

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm still not sure what the actual problem you're having is...I can't get Gson to give me a null.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonUrlParse {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Url url = new Url( "foo" );
        System.out.println( new Gson().toJson( url ) );
        Url nurl = new Url( null );
        System.out.println( new Gson().toJson( nurl ) );
    }
}

class Url {
    String url;
    public Url( String url ) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Output:

{"url":"foo"}

{}

Comment: try to put class `Url` inside class `GsonUrlParse` like the example above.

Comment: @GertCuykens Huh, ok, yeah. I don't have an answer, per se, but I do have a guess: because the class is a 'local class', nothing outside the enclosing brackets has any idea what it is - including Gson. If you define it as an internal class instead, it should work.

Comment: True, but I find it hard to believe there is no way to define a local class differently, so that Gson can find a local class, maybe with a annotation I don't know off or something?